# When trying to "Make Segment" it connects wrong points

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry, shape-keys

I have curves as shown on picture below and I want to make them become one whole segment (as it happened to a "plain" to the left of selected curves (both are separate objects).

[image: Selected curves to the right and segmented curve to the left]

After pressing pressing "Make Segment" (button "F") it connects wrong points and doesn't transform to a "plain" form.

[image: Wrong points are connected]

Bottom edge of that shape (curve on the right) is a duplicate copy of points from the left one and it looks like that it connects points, which where ends of copied edge.
Both curves geometry are 2d, Fill mode: both and have same extrude.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It would help Blender find out which segments you want to connect if you would just select two control points with a gap between them and then press `F` to fill them one after another. The other thing is, to fill the last gap, you have to go to the _Curve Properties_ > _Active Spline_ and enable _Cyclic_. Otherwise the curve will always be open with a start and end point. If this does not work we really might need your file to find out what is going on there.

Comment: I agree making the curve cyclic should solve your problem. Also you have a dupe control point there you might want to check it out.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M597.png Control points can have at most 2 handles